# Is there a way to get psycopg2 to return the points as python tuples?

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

I want to retrieve a PostGIS point column from Postgres as a python tuple using psycopg2.

This is proving surprisingly difficult. I'm puzzled that psycopg2 does not automatically read [Postgres point types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-geometric.html) (setting aside PostGIS point geometries) as python tuples.

For example, I would expect `row['latlng_tuple']` in the following code to be a python tuple of floats.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT \
    ( CAST (ST_X(latlng) AS double precision) \
    , CAST (ST_Y(latlng) AS double precision) \
    ) \
    AS latlng_tuple \
    FROM my_table;"

for row in cursor:
    print row['latlng_tuple']
```

Instead, I find that the above code returns `row['latlng_tuple']` as a string. This is consistent with [the way that the psycopg2 documentation describes the conversion between Postgres and python types](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types).

Why is this the case? Is there a way to get psycopg2 to return the points as python tuples, perhaps using a custom converter / adapter, as described [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adapt-tuple)?

Alternatively, is there an easy way to return PostGIS point geometries as python tuples? I've tried ppygis and found that it doesn't work.

Comment: Why would psycopg2 automagically understand postgis? postgis is an add on... So here's what I found. Not really much to read on it http://www.fabianowski.eu/projects/ppygis/

Comment: Posing the "Why doesn't.." question as the 'primary'/title is distracting of the goal.

Comment: @FirebladeDan - Yup - I agree! ppygis was the first thing I tried, and it doesn't work. You'll notice that the [last release of ppygis (0.2)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PPyGIS) is dated to 2011. It hasn't been maintained, and my guess is that it's fallen out of sync with psycopg2.

Comment: Would `query = 'select "latlng"[0], "latlng"[1] from my_table;'
rows = execute_read_query(connection, query)` solve your problem? In my case that becomes a list of float tuples.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL in the question returns a [composite `record` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html) with `(...)`, which is cast to `text`. For example, using native `double precision` types:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT (1.0::double precision, 2.0::double precision) AS db_tuple;")
for row in cursor:
    print(repr(row['db_tuple']))  # '(1,2)'
```

So you can't build tuples in SQL for Python. Build the tuples with Python:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT 1.0::double precision AS x, 2.0::double precision AS y;")
for row in cursor:
    xy_tuple = (row['x'], row['y'])
    print(repr(xy_tuple ))  # (1.0, 2.0)
```

---

To get data from PostGIS for other software, use the [geometry accessor](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Accessors) or [output functions](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs). For instance [`ST_X(geom)`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) returns the *x*-coordinate for a Point geometry as a `double precision` type.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ST_X(latlng) AS lng, ST_Y(latlng) AS lat FROM my_table;")
for row in cursor:
    latlng_tuple = (row['lat'], row['lng'])
    print(repr(latlng_tuple))

# (1.0, 2.0)
# (3.0, 4.0)
```

Also, don't confuse PostGIS's `geometry(Point)` type with PostgreSQL's `point` type. They are very different. Furthermore, packages likes ppygis are not required to get geometries from Python to PostGIS.

Comment: Sorry - perhaps I should have given a bit more info. The query that you describe above works for me as expected. But I'm using a [RealDictCursor](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#real-dictionary-cursor) and trying to select other columns besides the latlng. What I get when I try to execute `SELECT *, (CAST (ST_X(latlng) AS double), CAST (ST_Y(latlng) AS double)) AS latlng` is `[{ 'latlng': '(1,2)', ... }, { 'latlng': '(3,4)', ... }]`, etc.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's what I did. Thanks for the confirmation!